# Select rows per N and do a SUM

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in my SQL Server database with the following contents in it:

```
Date        | Amount
------------|----------
2012-12-17  | 9.00
2012-12-18  | 8.00
2012-12-19  | 0.00
2012-12-20  | 1.50
2012-12-21  | 2.50
2012-12-22  | 0.00
2012-12-23  | 0.00
2012-12-24  | 0.00
2012-12-25  | 0.00
2012-12-26  | 4.00
2012-12-27  | 2.00
2012-12-28  | 7.00
```

What I want to do is take 3 rows per select and `SUM` the `Amount`. If the total of the `SUM` is `0`, then it should delete those 3 records. Otherwise it should just leave them alone and take the next 3 records and do the same checks.

So in this case only the following three records should get deleted from the table, since they are the only ones where the `SUM` would result in `0`.

```
2012-12-23  | 0.00
2012-12-24  | 0.00
2012-12-25  | 0.00
```

How can I do his in SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to make 3 element groups and calucalte sum.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) - 1) / 3
  FROM #tab
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT *, [sum] = SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY [Date])
  FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE [sum] = 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/385768)**</kbd>

And with `DELETE`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *, rn = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) - 1) / 3
   FROM #tab
), cte2 AS
(
   SELECT *, [sum] = SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY rn ORDER BY [Date])
   FROM cte
)
DELETE t
FROM #tab t
JOIN cte2 c
  ON t.[Date] = c.[Date]
WHERE [sum] = 0;

SELECT *
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/385771)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

If your data can contain negative values you can use:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT *, rn = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Date]) - 1) / 3
  FROM #tab
), cte2 AS
(
  SELECT rn, [sum] = SUM(Amount)
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY rn
)
SELECT c.*
FROM cte c
JOIN cte2 c2
  ON c.rn = c2.rn
WHERE [sum] = 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/385783)**</kbd>

Comment: This only works if it happens that the 3 contiguous Amounts=0 fall into one partitioning group,assuming I understand the question